# System context has all permissions, but can't access file in share folder via Run Command in Azure. Why not?

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, active-directory

Scenario: We have a file in a share folder. We are copying the file from the share folder to a local computer using a PowerShell command run via Run Command in Azure:

`Copy-Item -Path \\SHARE_FOLDER\installs\MY_FILE.TXT -Destination C:\LOCAL\ -Force`

Run Command returns this error:

```
Copy-Item : Access to the path '\\SHARE_FOLDER\installs\MY_FILE.TXT' is denied.
At C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\1.1.8\Downloads\s
cript11.ps1:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Path \\SHARE_FOLDER\installs\MY_FILE.TXT -Destination C:\LO ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\SHARE_FOLDER\installs\MY_FI 
   LE.TXT:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsof 
   t.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
 
Copy-Item : Access to the path '\\SHARE_FOLDER\installs\MY_FILE.TXT' is denied.
At C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\1.1.8\Downloads\s
cript11.ps1:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Path \\SHARE_FOLDER\installs\MY_FILE.TXT -Destination C:\LO ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAcces 
   sException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.Pow 
   erShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Run Command runs as System ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#restrictions)). System had Owner Permission Level in File Sharing and Full Control in both Share permissions and Security (machine specific details have been blurred out):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why isn't System able to copy the file over? It appears to have all the permissions required to do so.

Adding Everyone to File Sharing fixes the problem. The file is successfully copied over.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to grant access to COMPUTER$ account on a share, not to SYSTEM. Check: [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/135867/how-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account)
Also it can happen that access to the share is blocked by firewall. Mare sure you can access it from this VM under another account.

Comment: Also check [Accessing files across a network using the SYSTEM account](https://superuser.com/questions/806955/accessing-files-across-a-network-using-the-system-account)

Comment: Your comment and the links cleared it up for me @Hardoman. Those computers access the share folder as COMPUTER$, not as SYSTEM. If you write an answer, I'll mark it as correct

Comment: thank you, I have posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing the network share you have to use network accounts. SYSTEM is local service account that they don't exist outside the machine they are attached to, so they are not part of the domain. You can have domain service accounts, but these exist as part of AD rather than accounts on a machine.
When using SYSTEM account on different computers you refer to different accounts.

In a domain environment, to access network shares you can grant access rights to computer accounts; this applies to processes running on those computers as `LocalSystem` or `NetworkService` (but not `LocalService`, which presents anonymous credentials on the network) when they connect to remote systems.
LocalSystem presents the computer's credentials to remote computers.

Each computer in AD domain is presented by a hidden object that can be found as `COMPUTER$` account.

> COMPUTER here refers to the AD name of the domain computer.

Accordingly to need to add `COMPUTER$` account in the NTFS and share permissions that this computer could access your share as LocalSystem.

Note: You can't use computer accounts in a workgroup environment; this applies only to domains.